# Firebase JS SDK on 'child_added' not working on large database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have ~ 1 million users in my users "table" on Firebase.

I need to fetch the username of each user.

`once('value'` is a way too big of a call, so I try using on 'child_added' but without any success, I am using this code:

```
usersRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  var user = snapshot.val();
  console.log(user);
  var username = user.username ? user.username : null;
  // Put username in the .txt file, one username per line
});
```

I waited as much as 15 minute, and nothing happened. It seems to be impossible right now. What could I try besides `child_added`?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving one million nodes is very unlikely to ever work. You're simply trying to pull too much data over the network. In that respect there is no difference between `value` and `child_added`: both retrieve the same data over the network in the same way.

Limit the number of children you retrieve by a query, either by a query:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("Dan P.").on("child_added", ...
```

*or* by directly accessing the user's node:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
ref.child(user.uid).on("child_added", ...
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work because I want to gather a list of all my users' usernames without them all having to login.

Comment: Perhaps contacting Firebase support directly so their programmers provide me that .txt file I want (all my users' usernames, one username per line)?

Comment: Also why would it ever not work? Will Firebase stop improving their service? This is basic functionality, it's a very easy task with other popular databases...

Comment: If you just want to export the data, you can use [Firebase's automated backups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/backups), use the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data) or a solution like [Firebak](https://github.com/alexklibisz/firebak) (which builds on the REST API).

Comment: Thanks, downloading the back up and will see what I can do with that. Most likely can use a stream to read through the (huge) file and gather what I need.